# It is proper to burn cards if there is no further action?

Tags: nlhe, etiquette

It is proper to burn cards if there is no further action?

i.e. all in preflop, or after the flop

Comment: Yes it is. Burning cards is standard and is done at all times. When there is no further action it is not necessary anymore, but it is still done.

Answer (score 2):

> It is proper to burn cards if there is no further action?

Yes, *absolutely*. There is no case where it is not considered proper to burn cards if there is no further action.

**Some Context:**
Cards are burned to prevent live cheating. There is no scenario where this should not be done.

**Reason:** Players can see the top card of a deck. If the next card has any physical marks that may help to identify it - without burning - players could know the following card. With burning, each card is completely unseen during action before that street.

**For example,**

> i.e all in preflop

Someone could intentionally mark an Ace when they get it, see the ace is coming on the turn (by the marked top card) and shove on the flop to knowingly hit their ace on the turn.

Comment: Yes i know why cards are burnt. Im asking if theres a need to burn a card after the flop and turn, if all players are all in preflop. i.e., do you burn one, deal flop, burn one, deal turn, burn one, deal river.

Comment: @sakon yes, this is correct burn one, deal flop, burn one, deal turn, burn one, deal river. Always, regardless of action.

Comment: @DanyyMahoney you are not answering the question

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans Thanks for your feedback, I have since added to this. Hopefully that covers everything prompted by the question. Please let me know otherwise

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Danny in that the cards should always be burned. This should apply even in the case of all-in preflop, for 2 reasons:

- while pre-flop, you can see the top card of the deck, so you might make a decision to do the all-in move you mentioned based on that information
- it's a dangerous precedent to introduce exceptions to the rule (or any rule) because, after a while, you will end up with multiple such exceptions, which can only be detrimental to both the integrity of the game and its learning curve.